# How to keep going to get average when restarting the Esper program?

Tags: java, esper

Does Esper support exception handling for restarts?

I want this exception handling

I'm sorry. My English is not good.
so I added picture.

[image: Description Picture]

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: The correct way to restart a service:
1., Reject the new requests (close the input and inform the clients about it by exceptions)
2., Process the pending data in the queue
3., Restart your service

Comment: Data goes away when stop a service. Then The average value will wrong If put the bakup data(average) after start a service.
In picture. I should get 5, but I get 6
because esper don't use backuped count when calculate average.
correct: ( 4 * (backup count 3) ) + 8 / ( (backup count 3) + 1 )
but incorrect: (4 + 8) / 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esper is in-memory only and does not have persistence. For persistence you need EsperHA that handles the save-restore.

Comment: If I make EsperHA that handles the save-restore. can I get the correctly average?
How can I make that?
I'm sorry. I don't know that how to make...